# Background gradient not showing on Holo theme

Tags: android, styles

In `styles.xml` inside of `values/`, `values-v11/`, and `values-v14/`, ive set the `AppBaseTheme` to `android:Theme.Holo`.

Now it seems to work well, except it is not showing the nice background gradient when I run it on a 4.2 AVD with API level 17.

I saw something along the lines of hardware acceleration. Could this be why it isn't showing the background gradient that the Holo theme should use? Is it something in the settings within the AVD? Or am I missing something else?

How do I get the Holo background gradient to show in my app when I run it on the AVD? I know this is purely cosmetic, but I think it looks nicer and I want my app to utilize it.

Comment: Yeah, the gradient background won't render unless hardware acceleration is enabled. It should be enabled with that configuration, but just in case, can you post your full AVD configuration? Alternately, try turning on hardware acceleration manually in the manifest and see if that changes anything.

Comment: If you're on the new AVD manager, and your emulator is made with this new manager make sure to set "Use host GPU". Also keep in mind that your app is utilizing the Holo theme, but your emulator is turning off specific, more hardware intensive, portions.